# API PLATFORM custom identifier in custom action

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to use custom identifier in a custom action without using {id} like this .

```
 @ApiResource(
   itemOperations={
     "FORGOT-PASSWORD"={
        "method"="PUT",
        "path"="/users/{forgotPasswordToken}/forgot-password",
        "controller"="App\Controller\ForgotPasswordController",
        "defaults"={"identifiedBy"="forgotPasswordToken"}
        }
    }
  )
```

But i still have the same error with "Invalid identifier value or configuration" .

Any issue please ?

Comment: Have you added use statement for the controller? I cannot know the exact reason without seeing the code.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, the controller works well but the request doesn't work because in custom action you can only get a resources with it's ID and not with another attribute like {forgotPasswordToken} in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Api Platform have a Read listener that try to retrieve the entity link to your item operation.

For your custom action you don't have identifier in your path like `{id}` to identify your resource, so the solution is to desactive the read listener with something like this :

```
@ApiResource(
   itemOperations={
     "FORGOT-PASSWORD"={
        "method"="PUT",
        "path"="/users/{forgotPasswordToken}/forgot-password",
        "controller"="App\Controller\ForgotPasswordController",
        "defaults"={"identifiedBy"="forgotPasswordToken"},
        "read"=false
        }
    }
  )
```

Comment: Yes but with this solution i can't acces to the new data (password) in my controller like this                                                                                                                                   class ForgotPasswordController
{
    public function __invoke(User $user, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->get('newPassword'));
        die;
    }
}

Comment: Yes you have to retrieve it manualy **or** if your token is persisted directly in your User entity with the property `forgotPasswordToken` may be you can add it as [identifier](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/#custom-identifier-normalizer) but I don't know if you can have multiple identifiers on the same resource (never tried it)